# Protractor: Run browser console command

Tags: javascript, browser, console, protractor

Is there a way for Protractor to run a command in browser's console (Dev tools in Chrome) with Javascript and read the result?

[image]

Or perhaps another way exists to do something like this?

Comment: Use [executeScript()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript) - "Schedules a command to execute JavaScript in the context of the currently selected frame or window"

Comment: Exactly what I needed `browser.driver.executeScript(function() { return api.Version; }).then(function(result) { console.log('API version: ' + result);    });`. Thank you Gunderson!